# html files are not showed when using eclipse, but shown in apache

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, tomcat

this is my project structure:

```
src/main/java
```

where i put all my code:

```
src/main/webapp
```

Where i put my `HTML` files (instead of the web content folder)

When i deploy on eclipse and select apache tomcat as server, the html are not there, and by that **I mean** when calling them, I get `404` error.

But when i do maven install and i copy the war file to the apache webapps folder and I run apache using `startup.sh`, everything is working perfectly.

why is that?

#### Note

just the `HTML` files are not shown when deploying on eclipse, but the other code (which includes rest api) is working and i can call them and get the correct response.

it is a maven project

Comment: What do you exactly do when you „_deploy on eclipse_“?

Comment: @GeroldBroser right click, run on server, and select tomcat